# Using presentation style from someone else's talk in my personal statement

Tags: citations

A while ago I have come upon a spectacular academic talk. The presenter, an analytic number theorist, used a unique take on a classic fable to introduce her subject (which is completely unrelated to the fable) ([link to a recording of this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDD0e-Q5nqU)). In particular, she presented analysis and number theory as two biomes interacting with another, and followed the path of a hedgehog and a fox as they wandered in the intermediate ecosystem between these two biomes.

I was really inspired the presentation style of this talk. My field is far different from analytic number theory, but as I am drafting my personal statement for grad school, I am thinking of following this presentation style. I am thinking of explaining my undergraduate research in the eyes of a hedgehog and a fox wandering around the meadow and forest, which symbolize the fields that I have been working in.

Here is the issue. I am not sure if directly taking her presentation style is appropriate or if it is considered plagiarism. Her talk was nothing short of spectacular, and I think her coming up with this presentation is a feat in itself. Should I use her style, and if I do, how should I best attribute her?

Comment: We all learn from each other. If her talk was so outstandingly original that you clearly derive - even just a stylistic - profit from it, there is no harm having the original talk/author explicitly in the acknowledgements of the talk. This way, you give proper attribution. Note that some caricaturists copy the style of original paintings and they say "after xyz". It is a nice homage to just state that the style of your talk was inspired or follows xyz.

Comment: Yes, it is a high compliment to emulate someone... and, of course, to give credit where credit is due. Let's not think about artificial rules, but about the really-quite-obvious ideas of fair play, giving credit, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give an exact answer, because the reaction will vary depending on the university and evaluators. Some might love it, others might not care, and some might even dislike it, thinking that there is no need to link your work to the stories of animals in order to prove your point. Therefore, there is always an element of risk involved, but this doesn't necessarily mean that you shouldn't go ahead with your plan.

Since you specifically asked about the issue of plagiarism, you should be safe so long as you do two or three things:

(1) Don't reuse any of the images/slides/drawings from the other presentation (create your own slides instead);

(2) In the last slide, provide some kind of brief credit, or written reference or acknowledgement saying that Dr. Pierce's presentation served as an inspiration;

(3) [Optional] Just before you start showing your slides, it might be a good idea to give a gentle notice, saying something like: "...and now, I would like to introduce my undergraduate research. I took some inspiration from a presentation made by mathematician Dr. Lilian Pierce, and so I will showcase my work from the eyes of a hedgehog and a fox wandering around the meadow and forest, which symbolize the fields that I have been working in." Perhaps some will think that saying this is a bit overkill, but it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: (3) is imo the correct (and simplest) answer. If the slides are not going to be shared further, then credit can really just be given orally and does not need to be written on a slide. The appropriate place to state that you have borrowed the overall idea for the talk from someone else is at the beginning. For one thing, if someone in the audience *has* seen the original talk, they would otherwise spend the entire talk up to the very last slide thinking that the OP's plan is to keep the audience in the dark about the fact that they are using someone else's idea.